# PHP my way of threating static classes

Tags: php, singleton, static

A few days ago I've faced an annoying problem. 
Let's imagine we have 3 classes: Base, System, Handler.

The classes Systen and Handler both inherit from the class Base.
I want to access those classes this way: System::DoStuff();
I also need the Handler be available in the System, but do not want to instantiate it there, use any kind of reference injection.

I could simply design the System and the Handler class to be static. The problem would be:
They need to inherit form the Base class, which should be static too, because if it's not, it won't work with the System and Hanlder because they ARE static. If is set Base to static, it won't work either, because once a child changes some parameter in it's parent, the parent would change for ALL children.

After some testing, I've came up with this solution:

```
class Wire
{
    //List of classes I'll have to load
    private static $load = array("Foo", "Hello");

    //Template of the Bootstrap class
    private static $template = NULL;

    //Wire everything up
    public function Up()
    {
            //Get the bootstrap template
        self::GetTemplate();

            //Get each class
        foreach(self::$load as $class)
        {
                    //Load it...
            require_once "./class/" . $class . ".php";

                    //Build the static shell
            $bootstrap = str_replace("%CLASS%", $class, self::$template);
            eval($bootstrap);
        }
    }

    //Get the tempalte of the bootstrap class
    private function GetTemplate()
    {
        if(self::$template === NULL)
        {
                    //I've stored it in a separate file
            self::$template = file_get_contents("./class/Bootstrap.php");
        }
    }
}


Wire::Up();
```

I'me using the Wire class to load the classes I need. And use this Bootstrap file to create a static shell for each instatiated class.

```
//This is the Bootstrap class
//It offers a static shell for other instatiated classes
class %CLASS%
{
    public static $instance = NULL;
    public function __callStatic($method, $arguments)
    {
        if(self::$instance === NULL)
        {
            $class = get_called_class() . "Controller";
            self::$instance = new $class();
        }
        call_user_func_array(array(self::$instance, $method), $arguments);
    }
}
```

That's the Base class, for testing purpouses only

```
class Base
{
    public $value = 1;
}
```

Here are the classes Foo and Hello that I've used above

```
class FooController extends Base
{
    public function Bar($args)
    {
        print $args . " " . $this->value . "<br>";
    }
}

class HelloController extends Base
{
    public function World($args)
    {
        $this->value = 10;
        print $args . " " . $this->value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Now, if you call

```
Hello::World("Hello World") //Hello World 10
Foo::Bar("Foo Bar") //Foo Bar 1 
//If Foo and Base would be static, whitout the Bootstrap shell, you would see "Foo Bar 10"
```

What do you think about that solution? Am I hunting a mouse with a shotgun? Or maybe there are better solutions, for this scenario? I'd appreciate costructive critics!!

Comment: Static classes tend to quickly move you in the exact opposite direction as OOP.  I have a feeling that there's a much better way to accomplish what you're doing, but after reading your post 3 times, I'm not quite sure I understand what it is that you are doing.  Why do you need to wrap some objects in a static 'shell'?  Is it for convenience?  Abusing them as globals?  Or what?  It seems like dependency injection is the right approach here, even if it is less convenient.  (Once again though, maybe I'm missing something -- not sure I quite get what the end goal is.)

Comment: Read my post below, please.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If it has mutable state it shouldn't be static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm just not understanding your situation properly or what, but I don't think converting three classes to static for one static method is really the right thing to do here. Why would you need to call `System::DoStuff()` statically? Why not just `$system->DoStuff()`? I would refactor the one method before I refactored the three classes. At most I would convert your base class to an abstract class to prevent its instantiation and I would define the value for the `$value` property in each individual class.

```
abstract class Base {
    public $value;
}

class FooController extends Base {
    public $value = 1;

    //etc...
}

class HelloController extends Base {
    public $value = 10;

    //etc...
}
```

You should use doccomments instead of those normal comments. They're more useful and can be read by your IDE.

```
/** List of classes I'll have to load */
private static $load = array( 'Foo', 'Hello' );
```

"Up" is not a very descriptive method name. What is it supposed to do? From your comments and your code it looks like its instantiating the class. So normally this would be in the constructor. I would suggest renaming this to something like `instantiate()`, or maybe `getInstance()`; And then I would make this a private method, or at the very least ensure that it hasn't already been instantiated so you don't end up doing it again.

`eval()` is evil. No seriously, it is. It is a horrible security risk. The only saving grace in this instance is that you have not written this in such a way that user input could be used. If you need to dynamically load a class, then you should just do so like this:

```
foreach( $load AS $class ) {
    require "./class/$class.php";
    $instance = new $class();
}
```

The `*_once()` versions of `require` and `include` should be avoided if at all possible. With a small number of files it isn't as noticeable, but PHP has to run a special check on each request to ensure that the file hasn't already been included, this means that it will run slower. Again, this is negligible in this case, but it could become an issue later.

I hope this helps, but I really don't know if I understood your issue well enough.

Comment: +1, but a small nitpick: Auto loading tends to be much more flexible down the road than explicit `require`/`include`.  (And it can have very similar performance with a simple autoloader.)  The problem essentially boils down to that the `$class` may have already been loaded.  Not likely in a simple case like this though.  (And in all but a few edge cases, attempting to double load classes is a very bad sign.)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether I should mention autoloading or not, but you are correct, it would be.

Comment: Read my post below, please.

Comment: @maximkott: You should remove your "answer" and edit your question with that information. I don't understand why you would not want to instantiate a class. That single limitation, and your static solution, is the root of all your problems. "I want some classes be accessible as static ones, but behave like regular classes." That's contradictory, and I cannot imagine a situation where it would be necessary. It really sounds like you want a shared instance of a normal class, (persistence through sessions, cache, etc...) or maybe helper functions. As Corbin said, static is very much anti-OOP.